# Dynamically Assigning values to a swift dictionary from a csv file

Tags: ios, swift

```
func createWeightForAgeForBoysModel(result: [[String]]) {
    var meal_for_age: [Int:[String:Float]]!
    for row in result{

        let age = Int(row[0])!
        let severe = Float(row[1])!
         meal_for_age[age]!["severe"] = severe
        print(age)
        print(severe)


    }
}
```

How to assign values dynamically to an empty netted dictionary in swift. the assignment of `self.meal_for_age[age]!["severe"] = severe` keeps crashing.

```
var meal_for_age: [Int:[String:Float]] = [Int:[String:Float]]()
```

I had to place the declaration of the meal_for_age_variable below the method definition because of challenge to format the code on stack overflow text editor.

Thank You all for any help you can give to debug this

Comment: You check for `nil` and only if you verified that it in fact actually *is* `nil` you force unwrap that `nil` - what other than a crash did you expect? Did you mean to write `!=` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues

1. Basically the crash occurs because `meal_for_age` – by the way please conform to the naming convention that variable names are *lowerCamelCased* – is declared but not initialized. Declare it as empty dictionary

   ```
   func createWeightForAgeForBoysModel(result: [[String]]) {
       var mealForAge = [Int:[String:Float]]()
   ```
2. You have to create an empty dictionary for the key if it does not exist

   ```
   if mealForAge[age] == nil {
       mealForAge[age] = [:]
   }
   mealForAge[age]!["severe"] = severe
   ```

   or add the key-value pair

   ```
   if mealForAge[age] == nil {
       mealForAge[age] = ["severe" : severe]
   } else {
       mealForAge[age]!["severe"] = severe
   }
   ```

---

Note : **This does not work**

```
if var meal = mealForAge[age] {
    meal["severe"] = severe
```

because due to value semantics `mealForAge` won't change.

Comment: Thank you. Initialising the key was the problem. I will return to the conventional camelCase syntax.